# How to add button inside textarea using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My client wants me to create a textarea inside where there has to be a button like the below picture:

[image: This is sample]

Into the above pictue please follow into the right side of the picture where you can see blue color braces which is the button.

This has to be work like this 2nd picture on-click (like drop down):

[image]

Into the 2nd pictue we can see that upon clicking on the braces button the list has opened and clicking on an option from the list is writing on the Textarea. But this whole thing should work in client side i.e. using Javascript or Jquery in which I'm quite new at. So, I could not start on this. I need your wise suggestion on the above regarding how may I achieve the following meanwhile I'm also doing my research if I get to know anything then I will update my question or answer my question for other. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just create textarea and button separately and then position it by css (hint: absolute position) into the textarea. About the dropdown from button, try to have a look on bootstrap framework, they have nice components for that ;).

Comment: There's no way to put HTML inside a textarea, you have to create the button and list outside the textarea and just place it with CSS. If you don't know how to do that, which should be quite trivial, maybe you or your client should try to find someone that knows how to do it, as learning CSS, HTML and javascript from scratch will take some time.

Comment: Why don't you just make the button with the drop down functionality like you would normally and then just place it "on top" of the text area using absolute positions?

Comment: *Your client wants **you** to create* ... So go ahead, learn whatever is required to do it and code it! If you cannot, let your client know and give them the chance to find someone else more capable.

Comment: I'm going to try as per Rory McCrossan's suggestions also thanks everyone for your time.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To achieve this you can place both the textarea and button within the same div which has `position: relative` set on it. You can then make the button `position: absolute` and put it in the top right. Something like this:

```css
.textarea-container {
  position: relative;
}
.textarea-container textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.textarea-container button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="textarea-container">
  <textarea name="foo">Some content here...</textarea>
  <button>Menu</button>
</div>
```

I'll leave the styling for you to finalise as required.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer I'm going to try it and will let you know.

Comment: It really helped a lot. I've tested its working. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a version more or less as you asked, however, due to the fact that the container-div for the menu will have to be placed outside the `textarea`, there isn't really a way for it to dynamically fit to the `textarea` using only CSS - so for that you will have to use JavaScript.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#textareamenu_content ul,#textareamenu {
  display: none;
}
#textarea_container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
#textarea_container label {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  padding: .2em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: .2em;
}
#textareamenu:checked ~ #textareamenu_content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-height: 15em;
  min-height: 12em;
  min-width: 10em;
  border-left: 1.4em solid blue;
  z-index: 99;
}
#textareamenu:checked ~ #textareamenu_content ul {
  display: block;
}
textarea {
  min-height: 15em;
    min-width: 40em;
}
#textareamenu:checked ~ label {
  position: absolute;
  right: 8.6em;
  top: 0;
  width: 1.4em;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<div id="textarea_container">
    <textarea name="text"></textarea>
    <input type="checkbox" id="textareamenu">
    <label for="textareamenu">{}</label>
    <div id="textareamenu_content">
        <ul>
            <li>First_Name</li>
            <li>Last_Name</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```