# How can i put the buttons inside the textarea and limit the textarea size?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Someone can help, I'm not good with css, also, I want to show the image name if the person click on select file

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.btn-toolbar').on('click', '#foto', function() {
        $('#fotoInput').trigger('click'); 
 });
  
$('.btn-toolbar').on('click', '#texto', function() {
        $('#postText').focus(); 
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div><br>
          <textarea id="postText" class="form-control" placeholder="No que você está pensando?"></textarea>
           <div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar">
               <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                   <button id="foto" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="fa fa-camera"></span> Adicionar Foto</button>
                   <button  id="texto" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></span> Texto</button>
               </div>
                   <button class="btn btn-success" style="float:right;"><span class="fa fa-paper-plane"></span> Enviar</button>
</div>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="#" class="fotoForm">
      <input type="file" name="foto" id="fotoInput" style="display:none; visibility:hidden;">
</form>
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40951899/how-to-add-button-inside-textarea-using-javascript/40951929

Comment: is not the same, it wants to use javascript, I just want to put the buttons inside and limit the size of the textarea

Comment: you can use `maxlength` to limit the no of characters, What do you mean by size of textarea?

Comment: if you click the lower right corner of the textarea you can resize it, I would like to remove this option or just limit the size

Comment: `resize: none` works if you want to disable the resizable text area

Comment: ok resize works, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using textarea , use contenteditable=true.You can add html to div